# Web3 code working in terminal but not my IDE

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I am very new to web3 and relatively new to JavaScript. The following code returns undefined for the variable accounts.

Here is my code:

```js
const Web3= require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3("HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545");
var accounts; 
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(acc=>{accounts = acc});
console.log(accounts);
```

The code works completely in the terminal, printing out the list of accounts. However, it says undefined when I run it in the IDE. I have tried multiple things, such as even declaring a new function to be called from the `web3.eth.getAccounts()` as a callback, setting the account variable. Nothing works.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getAccounts()` function returns a promise which resolves later than the `console.log`, so before the `accounts` variable has been set.

You can either use the `accounts` variable after it's been set (watch out for the [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/))

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(acc => {
    accounts = acc;
    console.log(accounts);
});
```

or use the `await` expression in an `async` function

```
async function run() {
    var accounts;
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log(accounts);
}

run();
```